# Google chart redraw/scale on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, google-visualization

How do I redraw/rescale a google linechart on window resize?

Comment: this should really be a built in feature of the visualization api!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To redraw only when the window resize is completed and avoid multiple triggers, I think is better create an event:

```js
//create trigger to resizeEnd event     
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

//redraw graph when window resize is completed  
$(window).on('resizeEnd', function() {
    drawChart(data);
});
```

Answer (score 40):

The original code by Google simply does this at the end:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Changing it with a little javascript you can scale it when the window resizes:

```
function resize () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that when you fetch "data" over ajax , triggering a XHTTPRequest on EVERY window resize 'step' might be a bit stressfull on your server, I think it would be better to somehow cache the results of the ajax request and reuse that data, but your solution works for me! +1

Comment: wasnt working for me, needed to delete old rezults from div before drawing again: $('#chart_div').empty();

Comment: `window.onload = resize();` is equivalent to `resize(); window.onload = undefined;`

Comment: It works as you describe it when making the window bigger, but if you shrink the window you need to first empty the chart div, as Mantas D pointed out.  $('#chart_div').empty();  This will allow the browser to shrink the div, before redrawing the chart.

Comment: I like this solution. I don't like timers or recursive functions on client side, why consistently use CPU power?

Comment: Comments totally miss the point if you ask me. Is there no way to re-render the chart without re-passing `data`? The data didn't change, the window size did.

Answer (score 9):

Since the `window.resize` event fires multiple times on each resize event, I believe that the best solution is to use [smartresize.js](https://gist.github.com/randylien/5683851) and use `smartdraw()`. This limits the number of chart redraw’s per `window.resize`.

By using the provided js you can do it as simply as this:

```
// Instantiate and draw our user charts, passing in some options (as you probably were doing it)
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div_chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);

// And then:
$(window).smartresize(function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

Comment: misspell "otions" -> "options"

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way I can work out of doing this without causing too much stress to the browser:

```
    var chart1 = "done";

$(window).resize(function() {
if(chart1=="done"){
chart1 = "waiting";
setTimeout(function(){drawChart();chart1 = "done"},1000);
}
});
```

All it does is wait 1 second before the chart reloads and doesn't let the function call again in this waiting period. as window resize functions are called multiple times any time you change the window size this helps make the function only actually work once each time you change the window size, the rest of the calls get stopped by the if statement.

I hope this helps

Comment: Excellent for its simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option in Google Visualization API to make Google Charts responsive.

But **we can make Google Charts responsive as Window Resizes**. To make Google Chart responsive there is jQuery library available at [GitHub - jquery-smartresize](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize) licensed under MIT License, which has the ability to resize graphs on window resize event.

This project on GitHub has two script files :-

```
jquery.debouncedresize.js: adds a special event that fires once after the window
has been resized.
```

&

```
jquery.throttledresize.js: adds a special event that fires at a reduced rate (no 
more double events from Chrome and Safari).
```

Here are two **examples of responsive charts**...

1. [Responsive Google Pie Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/toddlevy/c59HH/)
2. [Responsive Google Bar Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/toddlevy/pyAz5/)

We can change the bottom padding of visualization_wrap to match the desired aspect ratio of chart.

```
Calculate as Height / Width x 100
For a 16x9 display it would be 9/16 = 0.5625 x 100 = 56.25%
For a square it'd be 100%
```

We can customize **chartarea** option of Google Chart **to ensure that labels don't get cut off on resizing**.

Answer (score 2):

Redraw/rescale a Google linechart on window resize:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is really inefficient since you just have to call chart.draw(data, options); again. This will fetch all information and do repetetive and unnecessary work.

Comment: how to force redraw example on click we force to call resize function.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the following approach, if You can live with using addEventListener, and don't mind lack of support for IE < 9.

```
var windowResizeTimer;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    clearTimeout(windowResizeTimer);
    windowResizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 750);
});
```

Note the use of the `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` functions and the added delay of 750 milliseconds, which makes this slightly less intensive when multiple resize events fire in quick succession (which is often the case for browsers on desktop when resizing using a mouse).

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on the same thing for days and I found out that adding an event works best.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", drawChart);
```

Just add this line after declaring your function and it will work fine.

Replace drawChart with the name of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these approaches

```js
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
```

```js
Chartkick.charts["<id of chart element like chart-1>"].redraw()
```

Answer (score -1):

Using **Tiago Castro's** answer, I have implemented a **line chart** to show the demonstration.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Compute Times');
  console.log("--");
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [10, 10, 15],
    [20, 20, 65]
  ]);
  console.log(data);
  var options = {
    height: 350,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Nb Curves'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Time (ms)'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  function resize() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  window.onload = resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<div id="chart_div">
```