# Google Charts How to make the Chart re-sizable?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I wonder If Google Charts API provide options to resize the Chart element? Or is there any workaround for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950761/google-chart-redraw-scale-with-window-resize

Comment: @jterry thanks for the link. I read that before posting. not sure Iam duplicating it. Mine doesn't actually involve window resize. just a control that allows resize. e.g. Chrome textarea

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment -- you could augment the solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950761/google-chart-redraw-scale-with-window-resize) by tapping into `jQuery`'s [`resize` method](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

```
$('#your_element_id').resize(function() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I'm assuming that the answer in the previous question is valid, but it's accepted so it likely is :)