# How to resize charts to fit the parent container with Google API

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

So I created a combo chart using the visualization API from Google, but im having problems resizing said chart to fit its parent container
[image]

That's how it looks on the website, The parent container's width is the one hovered. And i want the chart to fill the entire parent's width.

I have a panel system, in which each tab will have a different chart. the first one works like a charm, I dont have a problem with that one it fills the parent's container width correctly, but the second one is the one im having problems with.

Here's the HTML

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="anuales">
    <div id ="anual-bar-chart" height ="500px" ></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="semestre-1">
    <div id ="semester-1-chart" height="500px"></div>
 </div>
```

And here's the js file to draw the charts

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart", 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Año', 'Nacimiento', 'Reconocimiento', 'Adopción Simple', 'Matrimonios', 'Divorcios', 'Defunciones', 'Sentencias', 'Actas Foráneas', 'Promedio'],
        ['1997',  39520,732,39,10332,489,6033,88,0,7154],
        ['1998',  39113,728,61,9908,607,6261,82,0,7095],
        ['1999',  41007,825,58,10476,611,6103,74,0,7394],
        ['2000',  40337,898,30,10479,685,6198,80,0,7338],
        ['2001',  38132,847,10,9856,849,6288,78,0,7008],
        ['2002',  36933,856,7,9532,826,6425,96,0,6834],
        ['2003',  38688,858,63,9600,915,6731,139,0,7124],
        ['2004',  39612,919,40,9088,962,6674,199,0,7187],
        ['2005',  40985,1053,6,8785,1037,6874,215,0,7369],
        ['2006',  38863,1031,28,9023,1063,6954,164,0,7141],
        ['2007',  42757,1226,0,9318,1177,7169,3,0,8596],
        ['2008',  41310,1268,1,8842,1224,7676,1,0,7540],
        ['2009',  41155,1227,4,8185,1136,7757,5,0,7434],
        ['2010',  10867,1258,3,8268,1200,8250,3,330,7522],
        ['2011',  41760,1314,2,8977,1356,8077,5,987,7810],
        ['2012',  41553,1386,4,9240,1400,8622,7,782,7874],
        ['2013',  40953,1415,0,9726,1603,9107,11,622,7930],
        ['2014',  40981,1305,0,9713,1516,9349,5,619,7936],
        ['2015',  27017,887,0,6342,1227,3085,3,398,5245],
    ]);

var options = {

    titleTextStyle: {color:'white'},
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    chartArea: {width:'85%',height:'65%'},
    vAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
    legend:{textStyle: {color: 'white'}, position: 'bottom'},
    height: 350,
    hAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {8 : {type: 'line'}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('anual-bar-chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mes', 'Nacimiento', 'Defunciones', 'Matrimonios', 'Divorcios', 'Reconocimientos', 'Adopción Simple', 'Sentencias', 'Actas Foráneas', 'Promedio'],
    ['Ene-15',3865,897,586,130,138,0,0,38,0],
    ['Feb-15',3322,793,818,166,143,0,0,62,0],
    ['Mar-15',3314,802,745,156,88,0,0,52,0],
    ['Abr-15',3289,714,653,159,106,0,1,35,0],
    ['May-15',3153,718,662,155,20,0,0,37,0],
    ['Jun-15',3349,728,901,162,103,0,0,42,0],
    ['Jul-15',3254,697,797,168,10,0,2,70,0],
    ['Ago-15',3462,736,1182,131,123,0,0,62,0],

]);

var options2 = {

    titleTextStyle: {color:'white'},
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    chartArea: {width:'85%',height:'65%'},
    vAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
    legend:{textStyle: {color: 'white'}, position: 'bottom'},
    height: 350,

    hAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {8 : {type: 'line'}}
};

var chart2 = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('semester-1-chart'));
chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

The one that's named char2 at the bottom is the chart that im having problems with. I put the other one for u to see that I'm using the same configuration, but somehow it's displaying the charts different.

Can someone tell me what can I do, cause I've been looking around and there's nothing. I tried resizing the "chartArea" configuration that the api mentioned, but that only takes out the labels, but doesn't fit the parents container.

Answer (score 3):

Google Charts don't resize automatically. They have to be redrawn when things resize (and showing/hiding is a resize).
I believe the code below, which I ripped off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950761/google-chart-redraw-scale-with-window-resize) should solve your problem (you will need jquery too):

```
//create trigger to resizeEnd event     
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

//redraw graph when window resize is completed  
$(window).on('resizeEnd', function() {
    drawChart(data);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the same but with the even load instead of a resize?

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, document.ready is something like what you are looking for. Take a look at the [jquery documentation on that](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Yeah i tried and didn't work ... I figured out the way to do it though ... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if my suggestion will solve your problem...  Shouldn't you make two separate calls to draw the graphics?  Perhaps your first bar chart is influencing your second because you have them bundled into one function call.  For one of my projects I needed to deliver a piechart and a geochart and so I created a separate function to call them individually.

Please try this:

```
function drawCharts(){
    anualBarChart();
    semester1Chart();
}       
function anualBarChart(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Año', 'Nacimiento', 'Reconocimiento', 'Adopción Simple', 'Matrimonios', 'Divorcios', 'Defunciones', 'Sentencias', 'Actas Foráneas', 'Promedio'],
        ['1997',  39520,732,39,10332,489,6033,88,0,7154],
        ['1998',  39113,728,61,9908,607,6261,82,0,7095],
        ['1999',  41007,825,58,10476,611,6103,74,0,7394],
        ['2000',  40337,898,30,10479,685,6198,80,0,7338],
        ['2001',  38132,847,10,9856,849,6288,78,0,7008],
        ['2002',  36933,856,7,9532,826,6425,96,0,6834],
        ['2003',  38688,858,63,9600,915,6731,139,0,7124],
        ['2004',  39612,919,40,9088,962,6674,199,0,7187],
        ['2005',  40985,1053,6,8785,1037,6874,215,0,7369],
        ['2006',  38863,1031,28,9023,1063,6954,164,0,7141],
        ['2007',  42757,1226,0,9318,1177,7169,3,0,8596],
        ['2008',  41310,1268,1,8842,1224,7676,1,0,7540],
        ['2009',  41155,1227,4,8185,1136,7757,5,0,7434],
        ['2010',  10867,1258,3,8268,1200,8250,3,330,7522],
        ['2011',  41760,1314,2,8977,1356,8077,5,987,7810],
        ['2012',  41553,1386,4,9240,1400,8622,7,782,7874],
        ['2013',  40953,1415,0,9726,1603,9107,11,622,7930],
        ['2014',  40981,1305,0,9713,1516,9349,5,619,7936],
        ['2015',  27017,887,0,6342,1227,3085,3,398,5245],
    ]);

    var options = {
        titleTextStyle: {color:'white'},
        backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
        chartArea: {width:'85%',height:'65%'},
        vAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
        legend:{textStyle: {color: 'white'}, position: 'bottom'},
        height: 350,
        hAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: {8 : {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('anual-bar-chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
function semester1Chart(){
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Mes', 'Nacimiento', 'Defunciones', 'Matrimonios', 'Divorcios', 'Reconocimientos', 'Adopción Simple', 'Sentencias', 'Actas Foráneas', 'Promedio'],
        ['Ene-15',3865,897,586,130,138,0,0,38,0],
        ['Feb-15',3322,793,818,166,143,0,0,62,0],
        ['Mar-15',3314,802,745,156,88,0,0,52,0],
        ['Abr-15',3289,714,653,159,106,0,1,35,0],
        ['May-15',3153,718,662,155,20,0,0,37,0],
        ['Jun-15',3349,728,901,162,103,0,0,42,0],
        ['Jul-15',3254,697,797,168,10,0,2,70,0],
        ['Ago-15',3462,736,1182,131,123,0,0,62,0],
    ]);

    var options2 = {
        titleTextStyle: {color:'white'},
        backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
        chartArea: {width:'85%',height:'65%'},
        vAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
        legend:{textStyle: {color: 'white'}, position: 'bottom'},
        height: 350,
        hAxis: {textStyle:{color:'white'}},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: {8 : {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('semester-1-chart'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);       
}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
```

The more I think about it, this shouldn't make a difference.  Let me know if it is a bust and I'll remove it rather than copping down votes.